# Python Pandas Update Time in Cell Issues

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

Going nuts trying to update a column of time entries in a dataframe. I am opening a csv file that has a column of time entries in UTC. I can take these times, convert them to Alaska Standard time, and print that new time out just fine. But when I attempt to put the time back into the dataframe, while I get no errors, I also don't get the new time in the dataframe. The old UTC time is retained. Code is below, I'm curious what it is I am missing. Is there something special about times?

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from statistics import mean

def main():
    AKST = 9
    allDirectories = os.listdir('c:\\MyDir\\')
    for directory in allDirectories:
        curDirectory = directory.capitalize()
        print('Gathering data from: ' + curDirectory)
        dirPath = 'c:\\MyDir\\' + directory + '\\*.csv'
        # Files are named by date, so sorting by name gives us a proper date order
        files = sorted(glob.glob(dirPath))
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        for i in range(0,len(files)):
            data = pd.read_csv(files[i], usecols=['UTCDateTime', 'current_humidity', 'pm2_5_cf_1', 'pm2_5_cf_1_b'])
            dfTemp = pd.DataFrame(data) # Temporary dataframe to hold our new info
            df = pd.concat([df, dfTemp], axis=0) # Add new info to end of dataFrame
        print("Converting UTC to AKST, this may take a moment.")
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            convertedDT = datetime.strptime(row['UTCDateTime'], '%Y/%m/%dT%H:%M:%Sz') - pd.DateOffset(hours=AKST)
            print("UTC: " + row['UTCDateTime'])
            df.at[index,'UTCDateTime'] = convertedDT
            print("AKST: " + str(convertedDT))
            print("row['UTCDateTime] = " + row['UTCDateTime'] + '\n') # Should be updated with AKST, but is not!
```

Edit - Alternatively: Is there a way to go about converting the date when it is first read in to the dataframe? Seems like that would be faster than having two for loops.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it looks like the data is getting updated correctly in the dataframe, but **you are printing the row, which is not updated**, as it was fetched from dataframe before its updation!

```
 #You are updating df
 df.at[index,'UTCDateTime'] = convertedDT #You are updating df
 # below you are printing row
 print("row['UTCDateTime] = " + row['UTCDateTime']
```

See sample code below and its output for the explanation.

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'Year':  [1982,1983], 'Statut':['Yes',  'No']})
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    data.at[index, 'Year'] = '5000' + str(index)
    print('Printing row which is unchanged : ', row['Year'])
print('Updated Dataframe\n',data)
```

**Output**

```
Printing row which is unchanged :  1982
Printing row which is unchanged :  1983
Updated Dataframe
     Year Statut
0  50000    Yes
1  50001     No
```

Comment: I am certainly still in learning mode when it comes to python. Thanks much for this explanation.